# Get first link of wikipedia article using Wikipedia api

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have come across the following question: [Get the first link in a Wikipedia article not inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634278/get-the-first-link-in-a-wikipedia-article-not-inside-parentheses) and I am trying to get the same result.

However, the method privileged in the question I cite is to parse the whole wikipedia page in order to get the desired link.

I would prefer to use the [wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) but I have come across a major issues: I don't know how (or if it is even possible) to order links by appearance in the page.

The request I have for now is the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=United_States&prop=links&pllimit=max

Comment: No, `prop=links` will not tell you the order of link. For that, you will need to parse at least the first section of the article (assuming the first link is in there).

Comment: @svick I know that prop=links does not work, but I would still like to know if there is a better way. I am implementing a parser in the mean time. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like it is not possible to do this using the API. So I coded a parser in Python and BeautifulSoup. Here is the implementation:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

template = "https://wikipedia.org"    

def isValid(ref,paragraph):
   if not ref or "#" in ref or "//" in ref or ":" in ref:
      return False
   if "/wiki/" not in ref:
      return False
   if ref not in paragraph:
      return False
   prefix = paragraph.split(ref,1)[0]
   if prefix.count("(")!=prefix.count(")"):
      return False
   return True

def validateTag(tag):
   name = tag.name
   isParagraph = name == "p"
   isList = name == "ul"
   return isParagraph or isList

def getFirstLink(wikipage):
   req = urllib2.Request(template+wikipage, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
   page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   data = page.read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
   soup = soup.find(id="mw-content-text")
   for paragraph in soup.find_all(validateTag, recursive=False):
      for link in paragraph.find_all("a"):
         ref = link.get("href")
         if isValid(str(ref),str(paragraph)):
            return link
   return False
```

If you want to see more about this project, here is the github page with the whole source code: https://github.com/ChrisJamesC/wikipediaPhilosophy